# Crash Reporting Tools Privacy Concerns

Tags: android, ios, crashlytics, hockeyapp

We are wanting to integrate a crash reporting SDK such as Crashlytics or Hockeyapp into an iOS and Android app for one of our clients. The client wants to confirm if there is anything extra that should be including in the app's privacy policy because of one of these services being added. We plan on integrating one of the SDK's to automatically crash send in data without a prompt. Is there any privacy related concerns in regards to integrating these?